# How to use Custom attributes with MonoTouch and F#

Tags: f#, xamarin.ios

I would like to use some introspection with F# and MonoTouch.

Given the following code fragments:

```
type Field (aName : string) =
    inherit Attribute()    
    member this.Name = aName

[<Field("title")>]                             
    member this.Title with get() = title
```

I expected to get the Attribute back with:

```
reflection.GetCustomAttributes(typeof<Field>, false)
```

But that does not work.

But

```
reflection.GetCustomAttributes(false)
```

works but it just returns an array of objects.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Regards
  Roger

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. Renamed the attribute from Field to FieldInfo and it worked.

Regards
 Roger